# print key of first element of array_search() in php

Tags: php

I have following code

```
 public static $_myarray = array('This is S' => 'S',
                          'This is RC' => 'RC',
                          'This is RF' => 'RF',
                          'This is C' => 'C');

 $check_var = 'S';
```

i am trying to get this

```
echo $key_of_array =  array_search($check_var,$_myarray); // output should be 'This is S'
```

it is returning blank value instead of "This is S"

I tried with following as well.

-> type casting of $check_var

-> array_search($check_var,$_myarray,true);

but no luck. can anyone please help me to sort out this ?

Note : it works well for other values .. issue is only with first element of array .. and i am checking this on Linux

Comment: Your code is good, it will give the result as you want. Will you please do print_r($key_of_array) and tell what the result will?

Comment: @KinjalMistry : print_r($key_of_array) prints nothing :(

Comment: Why you are doing your array as static?! I think you should try by removing this as well, remove (public static). Hope this will do for you.

Comment: tried removing that also . not working . i think "public static" has nothing to restrict array_search() function

Comment: array_search is return key value only

Comment: @Yaxitashah Will you please put your full code?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), `Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.` so here is where your empty string comes from.

```
$_myarray = [
    'This is S' => 'S',
    'This is RC' => 'RC',
    'This is RF' => 'RF',
    'This is C' => 'C'
];

$check_var = 'S';

echo array_search($check_var,$_myarray);
echo array_search('S',$_myarray);
```

Works for me.

Comment: Above one is not working for me .. you may have checked this on windows .. i am using Linux .. Linux is more restricted .. may be thats why not working at my side

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux running PHP 7.0.2, but it should not make a difference. Perhaps its your document encoding, try copy pasting this code in a new file encoded with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works,but if you are out of a class scope it should give an error..

check this [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%5Cn%3C?php%5Cn//echo%20phpinfo();%5Cn/*public*/%20$_myarray%20=%20array(%27This%20is%20S%27%20=%3E%20%27S%27,%20//note%20that%20public%20keyword%20gives%20an%20error%20out%20of%20class%20scope..%5Cn%20%27This%20is%20RC%27%20=%3E%20%27RC%27,%5Cn%20%27This%20is%20RF%27%20=%3E%20%27RF%27,%5Cn%20%27This%20is%20C%27%20=%3E%20%27C%27);%5Cn%5Cn$check_var%20=%20%27S%27;%5Cnecho%20$key_of_array%20=%20array_search($check_var,$_myarray);%20//%20output%20should%20be%20%27This%20is%20S%27%5Cn)

```
   <?php
    //echo phpinfo();
    /*public*/ $_myarray = array('This is S' => 'S', //note that public keyword causes an error out of class scope..
                              'This is RC' => 'RC',
                              'This is RF' => 'RF',
                              'This is C' => 'C');

    $check_var = 'S';
    echo $key_of_array =  array_search($check_var,$_myarray); // output should be 'This is S'
```